# Using secure connection with RemoteWebDriver and Selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver

It seems that when using Selenium RemoteWebDriver all the commands that are sent to the servlet container in plain text, for the most part this isn't an issue, but my concern is that test data is sent in the same way. i.e. Usernames and Passwords to login to personalised areas of the website undertest. Has anyone encountered a requirement to have these be handled securely, and if so how did you go about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the best way to achieve this would be to use a secure tunnel, and send all http traffic that selenium generates over that